# Inputing values into MySQL from Python

Tags: python, mysql

I have 2 questions:
I was trying to input values into a MySQL table, I kept on getting an error when I tried to input date type object in MySQL.

MySQL expects this;

```
Settlement  DATE DEFAULT NULL
```

What my Python program is passing is this:

```
<type 'datetime.date'>
```

Are these 2 compatible?

Also, my variable `date` is a variable which I convert to `datetime.date` object, which I then pass to MySQL. If for some reason, I couldn't get any dates for variable `date`, could I still pass `None` to MySQL, which is expecting a date?

Comment: Post your complete code, mate.

Comment: You can convert your date into a string format that MySQL likes using [strftime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime). Check out the formatting guidelines [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior). For example, to get yyyy-mm-dd format, you can call `datetime.datetime.strftime(date_, '%Y-%m-%d')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass now() in your query to get mysql to store current date/time.

Or to convert python datetime into mysql compatible datetime use:-

```
now = datetime.datetime(2013,08,07)
str_now = now.date().isoformat()
```

Send str_now in datetime field to mysql